# Adapting a wordpress search to search multiple fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to adapt an existing search to allow for searches for not only staff names but also their titles (job roles).

Currently the following is the form method:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('staff'); ?>" class="search" data-behavior="search">
```

and this is the `get_post_type_archive_link` function

```
function get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( ! $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type ) )
        return false;

    if ( ! $post_type_obj->has_archive )
        return false;

    if ( get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) && is_array( $post_type_obj->rewrite ) ) {
        $struct = ( true === $post_type_obj->has_archive ) ? $post_type_obj->rewrite['slug'] : $post_type_obj->has_archive;
        if ( $post_type_obj->rewrite['with_front'] )
            $struct = $wp_rewrite->front . $struct;
        else
            $struct = $wp_rewrite->root . $struct;
        $link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $struct, 'post_type_archive' ) );
    } else {
        $link = home_url( '?post_type=' . $post_type );
    }

    return apply_filters( 'post_type_archive_link', $link, $post_type );
}
```

Comment: What does this function do presently? I am not a WP dev, but I wonder whether people who are will find this easier to answer if they understand the difference between what you have and what you want.

Comment: thank you! this is part of the problem. I did not initially write this code and the person who did has now left. That function is what relates to the search action and thats as far as I have got. Currently what is happening is there is a search form at the top of the page followed by a listing of staff and links to their profiles. I need to make it work so the search works not only for name but also searches the title (job role) if someone wants to search for all people with a certain job.

Answer (score 2):

This function has nothing to do with searching your Wordpress database. Instead, it is echoing out a url which tells the form where to submit. What you need to find out is what happens once the form is submitted to that url. There are some standard Wordpress functions and filters for searching, but I'm guessing based what you've shown here that there is also some custom functionality in the code somewhere which is executing a search somehow using the word "staff".

Where is this function? Is this in a plugin? A Theme? Are there other functions around it? I would suggest looking around in the general area of this function for something that has some sql queries and paste *that* function here for us to look at.

Comment: I'd add to this that if the current code can be added to version control (or at least a copy taken) then you can add `echo` statements to trace execution in themes/plugins etc until the search functionality is found. Then at least you'll know which bit to modify!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand right, but follows a custom search for titles, content and also for Custom Fields (if you have)

```
  <?php //LOOP PARA BUSCA COM TODOS CUSTOM FIELD
  $keyword = get_search_query();
  $keyword = '%' . like_escape( $keyword ) . '%'; // Thanks Manny Fleurmond
 // SEARCH FROM ALL CUSTOM FIELDS
$post_ids_meta = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
ALTER TABLE wp_posts ADD INDEX (postmeta)
SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_value LIKE '%s'
", $keyword ) );

// SEARCH FOR TITLE AND CONTENT
$post_ids_post = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
ALTER TABLE wp_post s ADD INDEX (posts);
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_title LIKE '%s'
OR post_content LIKE '%s'
", $keyword, $keyword ) );
$post_ids = array_merge( $post_ids_meta, $post_ids_post );

$wpq = array(
'taxonomy'=>'segmento',

'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'CUSTOM-POST-TYPE',
'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
'post__in' => $post_ids,
'order' => 'ASC',

  );

  query_posts($wpq);
```

Good Luck